# Setting Apache timeouts only half working

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have an EC2 instance running django and a page requires a post request which lasts for about a minute and a half.

This initially timed out at 60 seconds, however tinkering with the httpd.conf resolved this issue. I added `inactivity-timeout=600`:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED>
    Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
    WSGIDaemonProcess myname processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} inactivity-timeout=600
</IfDefine>

...

</VirtualHost>
```

and also:

```
TimeOut 600
```

but I also have `mydomain.com` pointed at the instance, and on the same page, accessed through `mydomain.com` continues to timeout at 60 seconds.

I've been tweaking my `httpd.conf` for hours but nothing seems to make any difference...

Am I something anything obvious?